# Debug memory consumption\leaks of already running script

Tags: python, debugging, python-2.7, memory-leaks, gdb

I have a Python program that started eating a lot of RAM. The problem is that it has been working for around 2 days with no issues, but started eating a lot of RAM suddenly. The script is quite large and it's hard to understand what's happening there.

Is there any way to attach to the running process and dump some info about objects? And thus I'll be able to understand what's going on there.

I used some python module for that, it reports me some data like that:

```
Strings: 4567, total memory: 45MB
Lists: 32, total memory: 12MB
Dicts: 1, total memory: 1MB
...
```

Of course, this is just an idea - any memory-related reports are appreciated.

I found the only working solution to debug a running process: gdb. But I'm not familiar with it at all.

Please note that I don't want to change the code, import pdb, restart the script etc. - otherwise I have to wait 2 days more again.

Thank you!

Comment: You can attach to the process with `-p`. You can even use `ltrace`/`strace` to get only the memory allocations. See, for example, the posts in http://techblog.rosedu.org/tags/debugging.html

Answer (score 2):

On a glibc-based system you can use the gdb-heap extension to inspect the heap of a running process.  gdb-heap knows a bit about how Python does memory management as well.  See: https://fedorahosted.org/gdb-heap/